# docker compose is crashing and raises panic error of go routine running

Tags: docker-compose

Trying to run docker compose command but it crashes to give the Panic error of go routine running.

This is my docker compose file

```
###
version: '3'
###
x-airflow-common:\
  &airflow-common\
  build:\
  context: .\
  dockerfile: Dockerfile\
  image: custom-airflow:2.8.2-python3.11\
  env_file:\
    - airflow.env
###
  volumes:\
    - ./config:/opt/airflow/config\
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs\
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags\
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/\
    - ./data:/opt/airflow/data\
    - ./etls:/opt/airflow/etls\
    - ./pipelines:/opt/airflow/pipelines\
    - ./tests:/opt/airflow/tests\
    - ./utils:/opt/airflow/utils\
    - ./airflow.cfg:/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg\
    - ./requirements.txt:/opt/airflow/requirements.txt\
  depends_on:\
    postgres\
    redis
###
services:\
  postgres:\
    image:  postgres:latest\
    environment:\
      - POSTGRES_USER: postgres\
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres\
      - POSTGRES_DB: airflow_reddit\
      - POSTGRES_PORT: 5432\
    ports:\
      - "5432:5432"
  
  redis:\
    image: redis:latest\
    ports:\
      -"6379:6379"
###
  airflow-init:\
    <<: *airflow-common\
    command: > bash -c "pip install -r /opt/airflow/requirements.txt && airflow db init && airflow db upgrade && airflow users create --username admin --firstname admin --lastname admin --role Admin --email airflow@airflow.com --password admin"\
    restart: "no"
###
  airflow-webserver:\
    <<: *airflow-common\
    command: webserver\
    ports:\
      -"8080:8080"
 ### 
  airflow-scheduler:\
    <<: *airflow-common\
    command: scheduler
###  
  airflow-worker:\
    <<: *airflow-common\
    command: celery worker
###
trying to run
docker compose up -d --build / docker-compose up -d --build
```

```
##Error:

panic: interface conversion: interface {} is map[string]interface {}, not string

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/override.keyValueIndexer({0x106986700?, 0x140006924b0?}, {0x140004c5b38?, 0x1?})
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.3/override/uncity.go:111 +0x94
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/override.enforceUnicity({0x106842c60?, 0x140004c6e40?}, {0x140002fb500, 0x1d})
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.3/override/uncity.go:92 +0x340
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/override.enforceUnicity({0x106986700?, 0x1400068f830?}, {0x140002a9728, 0x11})
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.3/override/uncity.go:79 +0x160
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/override.enforceUnicity({0x106986700?, 0x140002bc990?}, {0x1063d7ac2, 0x8})
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.3/override/uncity.go:79 +0x160
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/override.enforceUnicity({0x106986700?, 0x1400017fd40?}, {0x0, 0x0})
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.3/override/uncity.go:79 +0x160
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/override.EnforceUnicity(0x106d68ba8?)
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.3/override/uncity.go:68 +0x50
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/loader.loadYamlModel.func1({0x106986700?, 0x140002bc630?}, {0x1400049e458, 0x1, 0x1})
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.3/loader/loader.go:360 +0x214
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/loader.loadYamlModel({0x106d68be0, 0x1400065c410}, {{0x0, 0x0}, {0x14000052b80, 0x64}, {0x1400038db00, 0x1, 0x1}, 0x1400038d020}, ...)
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.3/loader/loader.go:387 +0x784
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/loader.load({0x106d68be0, 0x1400065c410}, {{0x0, 0x0}, {0x14000052b80, 0x64}, {0x1400038db00, 0x1, 0x1}, 0x1400038d020}, ...)
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.3/loader/loader.go:443 +0x2ec
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/loader.LoadWithContext({0x106d68be0, 0x1400065c410}, {{0x0, 0x0}, {0x14000052b80, 0x64}, {0x1400038db00, 0x1, 0x1}, 0x1400038d020}, ...)
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.3/loader/loader.go:305 +0x3f4
github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2/cli.ProjectFromOptions(0x140002c6300)
        github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/v2@v2.0.0-rc.3/cli/options.go:434 +0x484
github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose.(*ProjectOptions).ToProject(0x140002980a0, {0x106d7b5e0?, 0x1400040c000?}, {0x14000414900, 0x0, 0x2}, {0x1400049f7e0?, 0x3?, 0x3?})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose/compose.go:216 +0x290
github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose.upCommand.(*ProjectOptions).WithServices.func4({0x106d68be0, 0x1400065c410}, {0x14000414900, 0x0, 0x2})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose/compose.go:146 +0xb0
github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose.upCommand.(*ProjectOptions).WithServices.Adapt.func6({0x106d68be0?, 0x1400065c410?}, 0x2?, {0x14000414900?, 0x0?, 0x0?})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose/compose.go:108 +0x3c
github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose.upCommand.(*ProjectOptions).WithServices.Adapt.AdaptCmd.func7(0x0?, {0x14000414900, 0x0, 0x2})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose/compose.go:87 +0x114
github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/cmdtrace.Setup.wrapRunE.func2(0x1400040c100?, {0x14000414900?, 0x0?, 0x2?})
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/cmdtrace/cmd_span.go:84 +0x58
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x1400041a300, {0x1400062c6e0, 0x2, 0x2})
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:983 +0x840
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0x14000031500)
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1115 +0x344
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1039
github.com/docker/cli/cli-plugins/plugin.RunPlugin(0x106d7b5e0?, 0x1400041a000, {{0x1063d2d4a, 0x5}, {0x1063dc7e1, 0xb}, {0x10671aa30, 0x11}, {0x0, 0x0}, ...})
        github.com/docker/cli@v25.0.1+incompatible/cli-plugins/plugin/plugin.go:64 +0x124
github.com/docker/cli/cli-plugins/plugin.Run(0x106d3b278, {{0x1063d2d4a, 0x5}, {0x1063dc7e1, 0xb}, {0x10671aa30, 0x11}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, ...}})
        github.com/docker/cli@v25.0.1+incompatible/cli-plugins/plugin/plugin.go:77 +0xec
main.pluginMain()
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/main.go:37 +0x98
main.main()
        github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/main.go:94 +0x1a4
```